# 'TestContext' does not contain a definition for 'DataRow'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uwp, mstest

I have UWP project. Using VS Community 2017 I added a unit test to my solution (Add project-> Windows Universal -> Unit Test App (Windows Universal)),

I added reference to my project, 
I added .csv file with test data,
I added DataSource Attribute

```
using System; 
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
 [TestClass]
 public class UnitTest1
 {
  private TestContext testContextInstance;
  public TestContext TestContext
  {
   get { return testContextInstance; }
   set { testContextInstance = value; }
  }

  [TestMethod()]
  [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", 
  @".\TestData.csv", "TestData#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

  public void ParameterizedTest()
  {  
   int value = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["Row1"]);
```

But still I can't use **TestContext.DataRow**

> Error CS1061  'TestContext' does not contain a definition for 'DataRow'
>   and no accessible extension method 'DataRow' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'TestContext' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Do I miss something?

Comment: please show us the "TestContext" class code so we can see how you have defined its "DataRow" member

Comment: @touseefbsb  I'm using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext class. According to [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx)  it has DataRow property. I haven't defined it by myself

Comment: is the using statement for this class causing any error?

Comment: @touseefbsb No, there are no other errors. I can use other properties of this class without errors

Comment: in that case I guess intellisense is also not showing DataRow?

Comment: @touseefbsb yes, intellisense is also not showing DataRow, but shows other properties

Comment: What version of the DLL are you using? I had a similar issue in the past which was related to the version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. There is no need to put *"UNSOLVED"* in your question title. That information is redundant, as the interface allows people to know, whether there is an accepted solution or not.

Comment: @ColinM I'm using Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.7.0 (also tried 15.8.0), MSTest.TestAdapter 1.3.2 and MSTest.TestFramework 1.3.2 - All of this were installed by default. Also TestPlatform.Universal 15.5.0.0 was referenced  by default

Answer (score 5):

Are you using .NET Core?

The .Net Core version of the adapter does not support DataSource yet as specified here https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/233

Answer (score 0):

My script is also the same as yours. Just put the below line of code in the .csproj file of your project you should be good:

```
<TargetFramework>net4.8</TargetFramework>
```

Previously I was using net5.0 but when I started using 4.8 I was able to resolve the issue. I hope it helps. Cheers

If you are still not able to get it please take a look at this repo:
https://github.com/manu1rock/RestSharpDemo

Above repo will help you.

Answer (score -1):

just use **testContextInstance.DataRow["Row1"]** and optionally add **toString** at its end like so **testContextInstance.DataRow["Row1"].ToString()**

> you are making a common mistake that you are trying to use **TextContext.DataRow** where **TextContext** is a class which has no static property named **DataRow** so in order to use it you need to create an instance of the class which you already have called **testContextInstance**.

Also change the property name from **TextContent** to **TextContextInstance** like following

```
private TestContext testContextInstance;
public TestContext TestContextInstance
{
   get { return testContextInstance; }
   set { testContextInstance = value; }
}
```

because you should never name a property exactly like its type ( class ) when you make this change now you can even use the property directly as you were trying before.

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(TestContextInstance.DataRow["Row1"]);
```

Comment: that caused the same error. Also according to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2017) I have to name it this way: "public TestContext TestContex {"

Comment: I think that must be a typo error in the docs, because that is not how you name a property also I have seen at multiple places of textcontext use cases in docs, there they are using textContextInstance, have u tried using it instead? its strange that even that is not working, maybe you are using a newer version of TextContent library which doesnt have datarow property.

Comment: I think I miss something, I have never created data driven test with DataSource attribute before, and I may not notice something important. But still I did everything according to current documents, and anyway using TestContext.DataRow causes an error (also renaming to  TestContextInstance)