# What i can use instead of DataRow property in contextData class in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, mstest

I am using VS 2019 with below versions

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" Version="79.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I want execute below code.

```
        [TestMethod]
        [DataSource(DATA_SOURCE, TFS_URL, "12345", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://XYZ..............");
            var userName = testContext.DataRow["UserID"].ToString();
            var password = testContext.DataRow["Password"].ToString();


       driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserID")).SendKeys(userName);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys(password);
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("k-button")).Click();
        }
```

Here ContextData class is not showing me the DataRow Property in it. It is giving error that

```
Error   CS1061  'TestContext' does not contain a definition for 'DataRow' and no accessible extension method 'DataRow' accepting a first argument of type 'TestContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    UnitTestProject1    C:\Users\nmodi\source\repos\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs  31  Active
```

Instead of DataRow or ContextData what i can use. or what i am missing in this code.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be implemented in .NET Core. You can check the status of this feature here: https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/233. As a workaround you can use dynamic data as explain in this post https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-data-tests.htm

Comment: ['TestContext' does not contain a definition for 'DataRow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245774/testcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-datarow) gives two possible reasons, you could have a look.

Comment: In Dynamic Data we are not define test case id. This attribute does not have 4 argument. I have to pass 4 attribute.