# TestContext.DataRow is not supported

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datarow

I am trying to convert a code from an old version of C# to a new one. Here is a minimal example:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Example
{
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
TestContext testContext = new();

object x = testContext.DataRow.Item(2);
}
}
}
```

A compilation error will be raised, as DataRow property does not exist in new versions of C#. How to handle it?

Comment: Does this [TestContext does not contain a definition for DataRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245774/testcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-datarow) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I know, I am aware of this duplicate. I tried to replace .net 6.0 by .net 4.8 but no results.